# On hover of a div, Overlay flickers and button does not respond

Tags: jquery, html, css

Below image shows the required scenario when user hovers on a div, covering div should behave more of, like a overlay or scrim.

[image: Scrim View]

So, far I am able to achieve similar functionality, but it breaks.

Problem is, when someone hovers on the particular div, overlaying div flickers a lot. Along with that, when i tried to click on the `EDIT` div (button), no callback made. I thought because of z-index, but that din't worked either. I tried to simplify my problem and created a Fiddle.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ve6zakqp/)

**HTML:**

```js
//jQuery

$('.edit').on('click',function(){
  alert('CLICKED');
});
```

```css
/*CSS*/

#maillistpar{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 170px;
  margin: auto auto;
}
.mailcover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}
.overlay{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px; 
}
.overlay div {
  position:relative;
  top:30%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.mailcover:hover+.overlay{
  background-color:black;
  opacity: 0.75;
  display: inline-block;
}
.edit {
  background-color:orange;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<div id='maillistpar'>
  <div class='mailcover'>
    <label class='lead'>A: </label><input id='email' style='float:right;'>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    <label class='lead'>B: </label><input id='desc'  style='float:right;'>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    <label class='lead'>C: </label><input id='weblab' style='float:right;'>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    <label class='lead'>D: </label><input id='bulls' class='form-control' style='float:right;'>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="edit">EDIT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would be great to have some helpful suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you hover over `.mailcover` `.overlay` masks it so the hover event is no longer in effect, `.overlay` then disappears which triggers the hover event on `.mailcover` again so `.overlay` reappears. This leads to the flickering effect. To fix, add the `:hover` event that is applied to `.mailcover` to `.overlay` as well:

```js
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
  alert('CLICKED');
});
```

```css
    #maillistpar {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      max-height: 170px;
      margin: auto auto;
    }
    .mailcover {
      width: 300px;
      height: 170px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      margin: 2px;
    }
    .overlay {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
    }
    .overlay div {
      position: relative;
      top: 30%;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    .mailcover:hover+.overlay,
    .overlay:hover {
      background-color: black;
      opacity: 0.75;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .edit {
      background-color: orange;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='maillistpar'>
  <div class='mailcover'>
    <label class='lead'>A:</label>
    <input id='email' style='float:right;'>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    <label class='lead'>B:</label>
    <input id='desc' style='float:right;'>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    <label class='lead'>C:</label>
    <input id='weblab' style='float:right;'>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    <label class='lead'>D:</label>
    <input id='bulls' class='form-control' style='float:right;'>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="edit">EDIT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```